# XSL parsing through input rounding all numeric values

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to parse through a document and remove all 0’s ending decimal places of each tag. The result should be the same of the input, but transforming all “10.00” to “10”, for example.

Here are some made up examples with structures that could appear:

```
<Order>
    <OrderId>1234567890</OrderId>
    <TotalOrder>506.40</TotalOrder>
    <TotalTax>17.00</TotalTax>
    <Currency>XYZ</Currency>
</Order>
```

Should result to:

```
<Order>
    <OrderId>1234567890</OrderId>
    <TotalOrder>506.4</TotalOrder>
    <TotalTax>17</TotalTax>
    <Currency>XYZ</Currency>
</Order>
```

An important thing to note is that Order’s children could vary. Therefore, my intent is not to make a template match for each possibility.

What I have done so far seems to be somewhat in the right track but results in the following output:

```
<OrderId>1.23456789E9</OrderId>
<TotalOrder>506.4</TotalOrder>
<TotalTax>17</TotalTax>
```

Xsl built so far:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:for-each select="node()">
        <xsl:if test="string(number(node())) != 'NaN'">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:value-of select="number(.)"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

It must be 1.0 compliant.

Any ideas?

---

Final XSL (suggestions to make it cleaner are welcome):

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">   
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:for-each select="node()">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string(number(node())) != 'NaN'">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(., '#########0.##')"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                 </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest that you start with an [Identity Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) and then override, using a template, the specific thing you want to alter, e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!-- identity transform templates -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@* | comment() | processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- match the text nodes where the text is a number -->
    <xsl:template match="text()[number(.) = number(.)]">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(., '#########0.##')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: this answer seems way cleaner, thank you! 
Another thing I have realized is that my solution does not work for nested structures whereas yours handle them perfectly. I will sure study this concept more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of your current xsl:copy

```
 <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:value-of select="format-number(., '#########0.##')"/>
 </xsl:copy>
```

Just put as many #'s in before the "0." as you need

doing this with you example I get

```
<OrderId>1234567890</OrderId>
<TotalOrder>506.4</TotalOrder>
<TotalTax>17</TotalTax>
```

Comment: Thank you @RT72 for the suggestion! I've tweeked a little the final expression to include the string tag "Currency" to the output.